# Google maps Geocode results undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-maps-api-3, request

So I am trying to geocode an address from google maps but when I try to access the results it says the array containing the results are undefined. I've have done the exact opposite of this with looking up an address from coordinates, granted that was in PHP, I'm not sure why this isn't working. I would like to just parse through the JSON to get to the data I want (The Lat and long), but since I am unable to do that, I have done a work around and just did JSON.stringify and locate the Lat & long via `str.locate("lat")`.

However, When I parse the json response from google maps I get this

```
    { results: 
        [ { address_components: [Object],
        formatted_address: '2985 NW Moda Way, Hillsboro, OR 97124, USA',
        geometry: [Object],
        place_id: 'ChIJt-G-MmcPlVQROzDAlEVj1nA',
        types: [Object] } ],
        status: 'OK' 
     }
```

Where the object inside the geometry is what I want, to get this I am using the request library from node.js. And I am console logging the `JSON.parse(response.body);` to get the results array but trying to get to the results object via

`JSON.stringify(response.body.results[2]);` results in 
`TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined`

Edit: Code I am using request for google maps API

```
 request('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '+' + parsedStreet + '&key=' + key, function(err, response) {
     if (err)
        console.log("holy shit error");
    console.log(JSON.parse(response.body.results));
```

which returns

`undefined
^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

address and parsedStreet are address values that I am reading from a file to convert into coordinates

Comment: Can you show us your `request` code?

Comment: For future reference, when you update it would be helpful to give people an @ reference in the comments so they know you responded to their comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access the `result` index before you actually parse the JSON into an object, so you're trying to get the `result` index from a string. You need to `JSON.parse` just the response body, and then get into the results, like so:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(response.body).results);
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, something as simple as a parenthesis.